# In Node.js/Javascript, how to check if value exists in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Lets say I have array something like this:

```
$game = Array
(
    ['round'] => Array
        (
            ['match'] => Array
                (
                    ['player_2'] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => asddd
                            [id] => 1846845
                            [winner] => yes
                        )

                    ['player_21'] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ddd
                            [id] => 1848280
                            [winner] => no
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

And lets say in Node.js/Javascript I need to check if `player_3` `winner` key value is `yes`. In  PHP, you did something like this:

```
if( $game['round']['match'][player_3]['winner'] == 'yes'){

}
```

Because there is no `player_3` it returns false in PHP, but if I did something similar in Javascript:

```
 if( typeof game['round']['match'][player_3]['winner'] != 'undefined' && game['round']['match'][player_3]['winner'] == 'yes'){

 }
```

I would get error: `(node:15048) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, because `player_3` doesn't exist in array and you can't check key value of array, that doesn't exist.

You could do this in Javascript:

```
if( 
   typeof game['round'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match']['player_3'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match']['player_3']['winner'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match']['player_3']['winner'] == 'yes'
){
   var playerIsWinner = true;
}else{
   var playerIsWinner = false;
}
```

You check each array inside array from top down and make sure that they exists. I don't know if it actually works, but even if it does, it seems bad and stupid way to check something. I mean look how simple it is in PHP, while in Javascript I have to check each array existence inside array. So is there better way checking value of array?

Comment: You could wrap it in a `try...catch` block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if array has nested property with defined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221381/how-to-check-if-array-has-nested-property-with-defined-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, look at the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library, especially at methods, such as [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get). Then you may safely try something like:

```
_.get(game, 'round.match.player3.winner', false);
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

The array you've shown resembles more of an object in JS. So here's what you could possibly try.

```
const obj = {
  round: {
    match: {
      player_2: {
        name: 'asddd',
        id: 1846845,
        winner: true
      },
      player_21: {
        name: 'ddd',
        id: 1848280,
        winner: false
      }
    }
  }
}

...

const isWinner = (key) => {
  try {
    return obj.round.match[key].winner
  } catch(e) {
    return false
  }
}


console.log(isWinner('player_2'))
```

By wrapping your return inside of `try ... catch`, you prevent the error from being thrown at your query and possibly stopping the app from continuing on. If from whatever reason the structure of your object would change, you'd still have a boolean value returned.

If you have to keep your `winner` value in form of a string, you could simply compare the value, and you'll end up with boolean as a result. As so:

```
const isWinner = (key) => {
  try {
    return (obj.round.matchs[key].winner === 'yes')
  } catch(e) {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: I think using something like lodash would be simpler and safer at this case. And it would be more readable as well. Don't you mind?

Comment: It definitely would be shorter, maybe even easier to apply. But I wouldn't agree it would be more readable, especially if you're not familiar with `lodash`. And honestly, I wouldn't install `lodash` just in order to use it once and forget about it

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to do manual check for deeply nested data for `null` or `undefined`, instead you could rollout your own small but compact function in this case `get` and be flexible with any input data provided. See more about [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
// this single line will do the trick
const get = (p, o) =>p.reduce((xs, x) => (xs && xs[x]) ? xs[x] : null, o)

// let's pass in our props object...

const props = {"round":{"match":[{"player_21":{"name":"asdfg","id":1846845,"winner":"not yet"}},{"player_2":{"name":"sany","id":1846280,"winner":"no"}},{"player_3":{"name":"sunny","id":1846000,"winner":"yes"}}]}}

var playerIsWinner = false;
//console.log(get(['round', 'match', 2, 'player_3', 'winner'], props))
if (get(['round', 'match', 2, 'player_3', 'winner'], props) == 'yes') {
  playerIsWinner = true;
}

console.log(playerIsWinner)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to avoid the undefined error:

```
 if ( game['round']['match'][player_3] && game['round']['match'][player_3]['winner'] == 'yes' ) {
   ...
 }
```

Because undefined is "falsey" you'll get false instead of undefined if player_3 does not exist, and true if player_3 exists and is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap in a `try catch` block. This allows you to skip all of your boilerplate `typeof`  statements:

```
   typeof game['round'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match']['player_3'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match']['player_3']['winner'] != 'undefined' &&
   typeof game['round']['match']['player_3']['winner'] == 'yes'
```

Instead throw an error and handle it if a element is not present. For example:

```js
let nestedObj = {
  prop1: {
    propa1: {
      propb1: 'test'
    }
  },
  prop2: {}
}

try {
  console.log(nestedObj['prop1']['propa1']['propb1']);
  console.log(nestedObj['prop2']['propa2']['propb2']);
} catch(e) {
  console.log('prop not defined');
}
```

This is a lot simpler than checking for every simple condition like you are doing now.